# How to enable color box near color strings in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, colors

How do i enable this rectangle near color strings?

[image]

It only shows when i'm inside the file `settings.json` of `vscode`.

When I have any string containing a color like:

[image]

That box doesn't appear.

Comment: write an extension that has a DocumentColorProvider

Comment: @rioV8 do you know any that does it?

Comment: you can search the vsc-extension examples, I don't know if there is one